# find_if on vector and compare member variables

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, stl

I have a class scene like this:

```
class Renderer;

class Scene
{
public:
    Scene(const std::string& sceneName);
    ~Scene();

    void Render(Renderer& renderer);

    Camera& GetSceneCamera() const;
    SceneNode& GetRootNode() const;
    const std::string& GetSceneName() const;


private:
    const std::string mName;
    Camera mSceneCamera;
    SceneNode mRootNode;
};
```

and then I have a vector of Scenes (`vector<Scene>`).

Now given a string I want to iterate over this vector of scenes and if the name is found amonst the scenes, return a pointer to it. Here's a naive attempt but I'm getting compilation errors:

```
Scene* SceneManager::FindScene(const std::string& sceneName)
{
    return std::find_if(mScenes.begin(), mScenes.end(), boost::bind(&std::string::compare, &sceneName, _1));
}
```

Boost is complaining about number of arguments, so I must have the syntax wrong.. what is the correct way to do this?

EDIT: `No instance of overloaded boost::bind matches the argument list`

EDIT2: Not C++11

Thanks

Comment: Please add the exact error message if you get a compilation error.

Comment: What if you just use `std::find(mScenes.begin(), mScenes.end(), sceneName)`?

Comment: Otherwise qualify the overload: `static_cast<int (std::string::*)(std::string const &) const>(&std::string::compare)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets take this in steps.

find_if will call a comparison function for each element in the vector, stopping when the comparison function returns true. The function needs to be callable with a `const Scene &` parameter.

We can write one like this (*all this code is untested)*:

```
struct SceneComparatorName {
    SceneComparatorName ( std::string &nameToFind ) : s_ ( nameToFind ) {}
    ~SceneComparatorName () {}
    bool operator () ( const Scene &theScene ) const {
        return theScene.GetSceneName () == s_;
        }
    std::string &s_;
    };
```

Now - how do you write it inline?
Your attempt with `boost::bind` fails because you're missing the call to `GetSceneName`, and you can't compare a `Scene &` to a `std::string`

#### In C++11

It's easy to write a lambda that does exactly what the struct above does.

```
[&sceneName] (const Scene &theScene ) { return theScene.GetSceneName () == sceneName; }
```

#### But you don't want c++11, so you have to write something like:

```
boost::bind ( std::string::operator ==, sceneName, _1.GetSceneName ());
```

but that doesn't work because it will call GetSceneName inside the call to bind instead of when the functor created by bind is invoked.

However, Boost.Bind has support for overloaded operators, so you can just write:

```
    boost::bind ( &Scene::GetSceneName, _1 ) == sceneName
```

and be done. See the documentation at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/bind/bind.html#nested_binds for more.

Comment: What should I write to do the same comparison as boost::bind ( &Scene::GetSceneName, _1 ) == sceneName does if the container instead of being vector<Scene> was either vector<Scene*> or vector<boost::shared_ptr<Scene>> ?

Comment: +1 for still mentioning C++11 although OP didn't ask for it, since that's what many will be using nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way is probably a manual loop:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(Scene& scene, mScenes) {
    if (scene.GetSceneName() == sceneName) return &scene;
}
return 0;
```